# Angular Material Chips appearing as rectangle instead of being Rounded inside a sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav, mat-chip

I created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i1v6xt?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.html)

If you open the side nav and then see the chip on the expansion  panel you will see its rectangular in shape but it should look circular. How do I fix this ?

---

> **Edit**: This is there as an issue already on [Github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9964)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chips must be inside a `<mat-chip-list>`.

https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview

```html
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip>Papadum</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip>Naan</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip>Dal</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: What If I want to use only one mat-chip I still need to add it to a list ?

Comment: @dota2pro yes, it must be inside a list.